# Elasticsearch "get by index" returns the document, while "match_all" returns no results

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to mock elasticsearch data for hosted CI unit-testing purposes.

I have prepared some fixtures that I can successfully load with `bulk()`, but then, for unknown reason, I cannot match **anything**, even though the `test_index` seemingly contains the data (because I can `get()` items by their IDs).

The `fixtures.json` is a subset of ES documents that I fetched from real production index. With real world index, everything works as expected and all tests pass.

An artificial example of the strange behaviour follows:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    es = Elasticsearch()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.es.indices.create('test_index', SOME_SCHEMA)

        with open('fixtures.json') as fixtures:
            bulk(cls.es, json.load(fixtures))

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super().tearDownClass()
        cls.es.indices.delete('test_index')

    def test_something(self):
        # check all documents are there:
        with open('fixtures.json') as fixtures:
            for f in json.load(fixtures):
                print(self.es.get(index='test_index', id=f['_id']))
                # yes they are!

        # BUT:
        match_all = {"query": {"match_all": {}}}
        print('hits:', self.es.search(index='test_index', body=match_all)['hits']['hits'])
        # prints `hits: []` like there was nothing in

        print('count:', self.es.count(index='test_index', body=match_all)['count'])
        # prints `count: 0`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can completely understand your pain (everything works except for the tests), the answer is actually quite simple: the tests, in contrast to your experiments, are too quick.

- Elasticsearch is [near real-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html) search engine, which means there
  is up to 1s delay between indexing a document and it being
  searchable.
- There is also unpredictable delay (depending on actual
  overhead) between creating an index and it being ready.

So the fix would be `time.sleep()` to give ES some space to create all the sorcery it needs to give you results. I would do this:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super().setUpClass()
    cls.es.indices.create('test_index', SOME_SCHEMA)

    with open('fixtures.json') as fixtures:
        bulk(cls.es, json.load(fixtures))

    cls.wait_until_index_ready()

@classmethod
def wait_until_index_ready(cls, timeout=10):
    for sec in range(timeout):
        time.sleep(1)
        if cls.es.cluster.health().get('status') in ('green', 'yellow'):
            break
```

Comment: Well, that's a hell of a gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While @jsmesami's is very correct in his answer, there is this possibly cleaner way of doing this. If you notice, the issue is because ES has not re-indexed. There are actually functions exposed by the API for this very purpose.
Try something like,

```
cls.es.indices.flush(wait_if_ongoing=True)
cls.es.indices.refresh(index='*')
```

To be more specific, you can pass `index='test_index'` to both these functions. I think this is a cleaner and more specific way than using `sleep(..)`.